# TCPListener not working?

Tags: c#, c, multithreading, tcp, tcplistener

As above basically, as far as I can tell, had some weird behaviour last night/this morning.
I rewrote some of my program to make bits threaded, and it seemed to work, then tried it again today and it doesn't seem to, and I can't see why it would act differently.

The code in question:

```
                Thread oThread2 = new Thread(() => test());
                oThread2.Start();
```

To start the thread, with the beginning of the thread below:

```
public int test()
    {

        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.149");

        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(localAddr, 1234);
        server.Start();

        Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection... ");

        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        Debug.WriteLine("Connected!");

        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
```

This thread seems to start no problems, however the acceptTcpClient() line doesn't seem to complete, despite the code on the server side being this....

```
pthread_t processThread;
if(pthread_create(&processThread, NULL, ProcessFrameThread, &incomingframesize))
{
        printf("ERROR creating thread!\n");
        close(conn_desc);
        close(sock_descriptor); 
        return -1;
}
```

Then:

```
void *ProcessFrameThread(void *inc_framesize)
{

int incomingframesize = *((int *)inc_framesize);
unsigned char processframebuffer[incomingframesize];

int sockfd, portno, n;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct hostent *server;

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(sockfd < 0)
    printf("Failed opening socket\n");

server = gethostbyname("192.168.0.149");
if (server == NULL)
{
  printf("ERROR, no such host");
  exit(0);
}

bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,(char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(1234);
printf("Client created, trying to connect\n");
if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
{
    error("ERROR connecting");
}

printf("Connected back to host :)\n");
```

Taken from a tutorial I found, as I said the weirdest thing being that it seemed to work last night despite me not changing anything as far as I can tell :/

This is my first time doing threading really, so I wouldn't be surprised that I've done something wrong it's just that I can't really tell what. On the PC I get 'Waiting for a connection...' in the debug window, and on the laptop I get 'Client created, trying to connect'. So it seems like the thread is being started, merely that they aren't finding each other? :/

I'm connecting to the laptop over port 1235 no problem, and was previously responding over the same connection, however when trying to make it threaded I didn't see an easy way to use the same connection so thought I'd just create a separate one for the return, on port 1234.

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: this is C++ not C code, please remove the 'C' tag

Comment: The server side looks like straight C?

Comment: making a comment about C++ is marked as useful. come on.

Comment: I thought I had just used C for the server side stuff, which bits are C++? I'm saving it as a .c, if it's got C++ could that be causing some weird issues?

Comment: Most of the code looks fine, except for the C code creating the socket handle. You are passing `0` as the protocol, when typically one would pass `IPPROTO_TCP` (which has a value of 6). For sure, the threading itself isn't the direct cause of whatever problem exists; as you say, you are getting diagnostic information that indicates the threads are executing as you expect them to. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to say for sure what the actual problem is. But try fixing the protocol parameter for your call to `socket()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think 0 means it chooses the default protocol, which I thought would be fine, but regardless, tried changing it to 6 with no luck. Having gone through line by line on the PC side, it gets to the "TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();" line and then just gets stuck. The server runs "printf("Client created, trying to connect\n");" then eventually prints that the Connection timed out :/ Going to try another port to see if there's some clashing.

Comment: This should basically work except if I have overlooked some trivial error or typo somewhere. Are you sure the network is not blocking the access? Try same machine access and disable firewalls. This usually excludes all possible network issues. Also bind on IPAddress.Any.

Comment: I don't think it is, as I've got a connection working the other way (coming from the PC to the server), and it seemed to work when I originally wrote it, don't think I was imagining it, I'll have more of a looksie at my laptop's network settings.